# cron works with enforcing SELinux even if crond_disable_trans is disabled

Tags: linux, cron, redhat, selinux

I have a Red Hat 5 with SELinux in enforcing mode :

```
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /selinux
Current mode:                   enforcing
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy version:                 21
Policy from config file:        targeted
```

even if crond_disable_trans is disable:

```
[root@rhel5_1 sf_personal]# getsebool -a|grep crond
crond_disable_trans --> off
fcron_crond --> off
```

but crond works with any user.

```
[root@rhel5_1 sf_personal]# crontab -u user01 -l
* * * * * /usr/bin/wall Ciao
```

This is the audit log file

```
type=USER_ACCT msg=audit(1346167741.137:35): user pid=2653 uid=0 auid=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:crond_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='PAM: accounting acct="root" : exe="/usr/sbin/crond" (hostname=?, addr=?, terminal=cron res=success)'
type=CRED_ACQ msg=audit(1346167741.142:36): user pid=2653 uid=0 auid=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:crond_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='PAM: setcred acct="root" : exe="/usr/sbin/crond" (hostname=?, addr=?, terminal=cron res=success)'
type=USER_ACCT msg=audit(1346167741.144:37): user pid=2654 uid=0 auid=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:crond_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='PAM: accounting acct="user01" : exe="/usr/sbin/crond" (hostname=?, addr=?, terminal=cron res=success)'
type=CRED_ACQ msg=audit(1346167741.144:38): user pid=2654 uid=0 auid=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:crond_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='PAM: setcred acct="user01" : exe="/usr/sbin/crond" (hostname=?, addr=?, terminal=cron res=success)'
type=LOGIN msg=audit(1346167741.144:39): login pid=2653 uid=0 old auid=4294967295 new auid=0 old ses=4294967295 new ses=6
type=LOGIN msg=audit(1346167741.146:40): login pid=2654 uid=0 old auid=4294967295 new auid=502 old ses=4294967295 new ses=7
type=USER_START msg=audit(1346167741.150:41): user pid=2653 uid=0 auid=0 subj=system_u:system_r:crond_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='PAM: session open acct="root" : exe="/usr/sbin/crond" (hostname=?, addr=?, terminal=cron res=success)'
type=CRED_DISP msg=audit(1346167741.153:42): user pid=2653 uid=0 auid=0 subj=system_u:system_r:crond_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='PAM: setcred acct="root" : exe="/usr/sbin/crond" (hostname=?, addr=?, terminal=cron res=success)'
type=USER_END msg=audit(1346167741.153:43): user pid=2653 uid=0 auid=0 subj=system_u:system_r:crond_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='PAM: session close acct="root" : exe="/usr/sbin/crond" (hostname=?, addr=?, terminal=cron res=success)'
type=USER_START msg=audit(1346167741.154:44): user pid=2654 uid=0 auid=502 subj=system_u:system_r:crond_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='PAM: session open acct="user01" : exe="/usr/sbin/crond" (hostname=?, addr=?, terminal=cron res=success)'
```

I don't understand why ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow/disallow cron for certain users, you should use the cron.deny and cron.allow files.

It may be possible to pose restrictions through pam as well.

I believe that cronjobs should always be running with context of the user running a cron job and SELinux enforces that if crond_disable_trans is set to on, while crontabs would not be restricted by contexts if crond_disable_trans is set to off. However, I could be wrong.
To get a final answer on this, you may want to contact your Red Hat support contact.